# Как сделать так чтобы после 10 нажатий(onClick) на кнопку закрывалось приложение?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как сделать так чтобы после 10 нажатий(onClick) на кнопку закрывалось приложение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте в вашем `Activity/Fragment` переменную которая будет считать кол-во кликов. При каждом клике увеличивайте ее на 1.

Как только переменная достигнет размер 10 вызовете этот метод:

```
this.finishAffinity();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое